# Taking input with discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I'm making a bot with discord.py and I have left a bounty saying that anyone who can solve the riddle gets 50$!
Now I want my users to post their answer to the bot in the dms, and this is the code i wrote!

```
@client.command()
async def answer(ctx, answer):
    print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + "[" + current_time + "] " + (ctx.author.name +"#"+ ctx.author.discriminator) + " Gave the Following Answer: " + answer)
    await ctx.author.send("**`Your Answer Has Been Submitted, Please Be Patient As We Review!`**")
    await ctx.author.send("Your Answer is: " + answer)
```

Now the thing about this is, it takes only the first word as the answer, while I want the bot to send the entire thing to me, how do I do that?

I tried using string indexes like
`answer[0:]`
and also tried adding str to the answer, nothing works...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using `@client.command`, [this is documented within Discord.py's documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments) (example lifted from the documentation page):

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

In your case,

```
@client.command()
async def answer(ctx, *, answer):
    print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + "[" + current_time + "] " + (ctx.author.name +"#"+ ctx.author.discriminator) + " Gave the Following Answer: " + answer)
    await ctx.author.send("**`Your Answer Has Been Submitted, Please Be Patient As We Review!`**")
    await ctx.author.send("Your Answer is: " + answer)
```